# Adding momentum to pulling force

Tags: momentum, torque, speed

A winch is pulling a 90kg object in any direction but it is limited in potential speed by its torque. Would a burst of momentum by perhaps a coiled spring or jet propulsion pushing the object towards the winch create greater speed of contracting rotations?

Also, is there a reason not to apply this sudden change in momentum to such a machine, if it is able to wind up at various rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the speed of the winch is limited by torque, then it is reasonable to expect that an additional periodic (or constant, for that matter) force should increase the average speed of pulling.

But the two cases you've described are not exactly equivalent.

In the first case, the additional force is produced by an external power sources behind "coiled spring or a jet propulsion".

In the second case, the additional force would have to come from the winch itself, but since the winch, apparently, already operates at its power limit, generating any additional power, to produce "sudden change in momentum", will likely cause overheating, excessive wear or other undesirable effects.